# Alternating table row color, but with 2 rows of data

Tags: jquery, css

I've got my table setup for Zebra striping, but how do I accomplish making the row color alternate for 2 rows instead of a single row?

My data markup looks like this:

```
<tr>
        <td>@task.TaskNum</td>
            <td>@task.RepiarTime</td>
            <td>Priority Club</td>
            <td>SD</td>
            <td>Commercial</td>
            <td>Reg Commercial</td>
            <td>After Hours</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="7">
                @task.Description.ToString()
            </td></tr>
```

I am using this to stripe it:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".stripeMe tr").mouseover(function () { $(this).addClass("over"); }).mouseout(function () { $(this).removeClass("over"); });
    $(".stripeMe tr:even").addClass("alt");
});
```

Comment: add an alternate class to the rows you want styled. I doubt you'll be able to rely on css rules for that.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work:

```
$(".stripeMe tr").each(function(i){
    if (i%4 < 2){
        $(this).addClass("alt");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

To do striping every two rows:

```
$('.stripeMe tr:nth-child(3n+3)').addClass('alt');
$('.stripeMe tr:nth-child(3n+4)').addClass('alt');
```

Comment: I think you meant 4n+3 and 4n+4 ?

Comment: With @PerryJ's addendum, I think this is the simplest and best answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not try nth-child? Here are a bunch of variations here. [How nth-child works.](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) I'm sure you can use the pseudo :hover instead of .mouseover in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.filter` and get the `index() % 3` or `(($(this).index()+1) % 3 == 0)`. See code below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/7An7k/)

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $('#myTable tr').filter(function () {
        //or (($(this).index()+1) % 3 == 0) if you want 3rd row
        //to be highlighted first.

        return ($(this).index() % 3 == 0);
    }).addClass('alt');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquerys nth child like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".stripeMe tr").mouseover(function () { $(this).addClass("over"); }).mouseout(function () { $(this).removeClass("over"); });
    $(".stripeMe tr:nth-child(3n)").addClass("alt"); // 3n selects every third element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a way in CSS to do this, but if you want jQuery try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VTSWT/)**.

jQuery:

```
var index = 0;
$('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass((index <= 1) ? 'odd' : 'even');
    index++;
    if (index == 4) index = 0;
});​
```

CSS:

```
.odd {
    background: #999;
}
.even {
    background: #ddd;
}​
```